# Vertically align div inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'd like to vertically align a div centrally inside a larger div. How do I do this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">

    <div class="middle">
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h2>Test</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.middle {height:160px;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;text-align:center;background:red}
.outer {height:550px;background:#eee}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zc09442a/

Comment: Am I missing something with your fiddle? Doesn't that do what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a rather simple technique taking advantage of css transforms, like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <h2>Test</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.middle {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.outer {
    height:550px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#eee;
    position: relative;
}
```

Your updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/67fvrLv0/).

You can also center the element both vertically and horizontally by adding a `left: 50%` property and changing the `transform: translate(0, -50%);` line to `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`.

Vertical and horizontal centering [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a66L3gfe/1/)

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps

```
.outer{ background:tomato; height:20em; vertical-align:middle; display:table-cell; width:50em; }
.middle{ background:green;  width:50%; margin: auto; }
```

http://codepen.io/jmonit/pen/LEzppM